# Access multiple pages with pagination in Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I have urls with multiple pages. I try to paginate to extract datas from theses urls hut it works only one time (juste one `next_page`). What's wrong ?

```
import json
import scrapy
import re
import pkgutil

from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from rzc_spider.items import AnnonceItem


class AnnonceSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'rzc_results'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        data_file = pkgutil.get_data("rzc_spider", "json/input/test_tt.json")
        self.data = json.loads(data_file)

    def start_requests(self):
        for item in self.data:
            request = scrapy.Request(item['rzc_url'], callback=self.parse)
            request.meta['item'] = item
            yield request

    def parse(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        item['results'] = []
        item["car_number"] = response.css(
            "h2.sub::text").extract_first()

        for caritem in response.css("div.ad > div[itemtype='https://schema.org/Vehicle']"):
            data = AnnonceItem()
            #model
            data["model"] = caritem.css(
                "em.title::text").extract_first()

            item['results'].append(data)
        yield item

        next_page = response.css(
            'a.link::attr(href)').extract_first()
        if next_page is not None:
            url_pagination = 'https://www.websiteexample.com' + next_page
            meta = {'item': response.meta['item']}
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url_pagination, callback=self.parse, meta=meta)

    #ban proxies reaction
    def response_is_ban(self, request, response):
        return b'banned' in response.body

    def exception_is_ban(self, request, exception):
        return None
```

The json file with the url (a sample in this case):

```
[{
    "rzc_url": "https://www.websiteexample.com/model"
}]
```

Comment: Does the spider not find a next URL on the second page, or is the URL found but it gives a bad response?

Comment: it finds a second page and scrap it but it stops here, even if there is 5 pages.

Comment: So have you an idea about this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Try and check the URL. Sometimes they set traps so only next_page has a absolute URL and another one has a relative URL. Instead of combining url_pagination with next_page use urljoin. Import it

yield scrapy.Request(urljoin(response.url, item), callback=self.parse, meta=meta)

Comment: The URL is the same, only the pages's number changes. And the result is the same with your code.

Comment: Have you another idea about my problem ?